# Mongoose create() function is creating a document using empty array

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have one mongoose schema defined as :

```
const OrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user : {
        type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref : "User",
        required : true
    },
    products : [
        {
            product : {
                type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref : "Product",
            },
            quantity : {
                type : Number,
                default : 0
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

Now, I am trying to create a new order using this function

```
const addNewOrder = async (user, products) => {
    console.log("Inside Order Controller :: ", user, products)
    try {
        const userOrder = await Order.findOne({user : user})
        
        if(!userOrder){
            const newUserOrder = await Order.create({user, products})
            console.log("User Order :: ", newUserOrder)
        }
        else{
            const userOrderMap = new Map()
            const existingProducts = userOrder.products
            for(let i=0; i<existingProducts.length; i++){
                userOrderMap.set(existingProducts[i].product.toString(), i);
            }

            for(let item of products){
                if(userOrderMap.has(item.product)){
                    const index = userOrderMap.get(item.product)
                    userOrder.products[index].quantity += item.quantity
                }
                else{
                    userOrder.products.push(item)
                }
            }
            console.log(userOrder)
            await userOrder.save()
            // return res.status(200).json({orders : userOrder})
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Order Error :: ", error)
        // return res.status(500).json({msg : "Internal Server Error"})
    }
}
```

Here, I am passing the user and a products array. However, after creating the document, it is showing that the products array is empty. What am I missing here ? I have checked multiple times and the products array is not empty. A sample products array is like this :

```
[
  {
    product: new ObjectId("64130385eae30b0aa5a27996"),
    quantity: 1,
    _id: new ObjectId("644f6bc3f47dce1957159f9d")
  }
]
```

What is wrong here ? Can anyone tell me ? Thanks in Advance.

I was not expecting an empty array. The create function should create a new document with the non-empty array.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are creating a new `userOrder` if it's not present in the DB, and the function ended there, i.e. skipped the adding products part in the else clause